# generating world in server minecraft (cant join)

Tags: server, minecraft

When i launching my minecraft server everything is going well at the start but when world is generating... well it is not generating completely. It says around 80-90% and thats it, server is launched but because world is not generated completely i cant join (my friends cant too). I've tried downgrading java, creating the new world, switching port or even the IP. [error while joining to server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgOZz.png) ; [console look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVTDj.png)

Answer (score -1):

Do you have legitimate Mojang Account? If not, the server will not let you join. I have a cracked version of Minecraft ([Tlauncher](https://tlauncher.org/en/)) and it will not let me join most servers. If you have a cracked account, go in the server properties. There should be an option for "cracked" or "online mode." Once you get there, turn on "cracked" or turn off "online mode." Note: Online mode is just a way to authenticate accounts. It does not affect whether or not your server can run online. If you have a legitimate PAID Mojang account, then try checking the IP address on your computer and make sure you type in the IPv4 address (on Windows, you can find this by typing `ipconfig` into CMD).